How to Use AWS SDK for Swift to Sign Requests and Make API Calls?
I'm developing an iOS app and need to make secure API requests to AWS services using the AWS SDK for Swift. I understand that AWSSigV4Signer is used for signing requests but am unsure of the correct steps to integrate it. Could anyone guide me on the following:
Setting up SdkHttpRequestBuilder: What are the essentials for initializing this with the URL, headers, and body?
Using AWSSigV4Signer: How do I pass AWS credentials to AWSSigV4Signer and apply it to sign the request?
Sending the Request: What's the procedure to send the signed request using URLSession?
Here's the basic setup I am working with:
let requestBuilder = SdkHttpRequestBuilder()
    .with(url: URL(string: "https://yourapi.aws.com/endpoint")!)
    .with(method: .post)
    .with(headers: ["Content-Type": "application/json"])
    .with(body: "{\"key\":\"value\"}".data(using: .utf8))

// Credentials - How do I use these with AWSSigV4Signer?
let credentials = AWSCredentials(accessKeyId: "ACCESS_KEY", secretAccessKey: "SECRET_KEY")


I'd appreciate any detailed guidance or examples on utilizing AWSSigV4Signer effectively.

I found some resources for you in Github and other platforms. You can try to use Amplify like most of people used.
Custom Github Repos: https://github.com/vkill/swift-aws-sigv4
https://github.com/benspratling4/SwiftAWSSignatureV4
Medium: https://medium.com/@lewisjkl/signing-aws4-31dcff1bf1f0
Amplify: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-swift
